# Auto change cell color based on auto updated cell value in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need a way/script to auto change the cell background between red and green if the updated cell value which is "=GOOGLEFINANCE("EURUSD")" is higher or lower from the previous update.

Is this even possible to do ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

I tried to modify this code to match my needs but this code doesn't even seem to be working, it keeps spitting: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')"

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var ss = event.range.getSheet();
  if (ss.getName() !== 'Sheet11') return; // Get out quickly
  var changedCell = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var changedCellB8 = changedCell.getB8Notation();
  if (changedCellB8 !== 'B13') return;

  var c = event.value;  // We know we edited cell B3, just get the value
  var background = 'white'; // Assume 1 <= c <= 2
  if (c > 2) {
    background = 'red';
  }
  else if (c < 1) {
    background = 'black'; 
  }
  changedCell.setBackground(background);
  ss.getRange("B8").setBackground(background);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need conditional formatting.  I think that's what it's call.  I do most things with code.  The cell changes due to formulas do not generate onEdit triggers

[conditional format builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is erroring out because the event parameter is first referred to as `e` and later as `event`. Therefore `event` is undefined, and `event.range` cannot be read. You can replace `e` with `event` to fix the error (but that will still not make the code to do what you want.)

The bigger issue is that you cannot catch formula updates with the `onEdit()` simple trigger — it only catches manual edits of cell values. Try an "on change" [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) instead.